# Build Akka library partly

Tags: java, scala

I want to add configurations to ***Akka*** library and build it again. It takes me a lot of time to build the whole project every time for testing the changes on a *jar* file library.Is it possible to build some specific part of project? Suppose there are no dependencies between the built and unbuilt parts. I'm working with Intelij 2019 Update which builds akka with *sbt* task.